# Using the function Map, count the number of words that start with ‘S’ in list in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to get the total count of elements in a list starting with 'S' by only using Map function and Lambda expression. What I've tried is using list function encapsulated which is not I want. 
Below is my code in which I've tried which is not desired.

```
input_list = ['San Jose', 'San Francisco', 'Santa Fe', 'Houston']
desireList = list(map(lambda x: x if x[0] == 'S' else '', input_list))
desireList.remove('')
print(len(desireList))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's more Pythonic to use `sum` with a generator expression for your purpose:

```
sum(w.startswith('S') for w in input_list)
```

or:

```
sum(f == 'S' for f, *_ in input_list)
```

or if you still would prefer to use `map` and `lambda`:

```
sum(map(lambda x: x[0] == 'S', input_list))
```

With your sample input, all of the above would return: `3`

Comment: It might not be strictly necessary, but the asker did specify that they were looking for a solution using `map`.

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer with a solution that uses `map` and `lambda` then.

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected. Thank You.

Comment: The `lambda` function returns a Boolean value as returned by the `==` operator, and the `map` generator maps the list items to the `lambda` so it outputs a sequence of Boolean values, or integers of `0`s and `1`s, which `sum` can then add up.

Comment: I'd also like to know as I'm new to Python. How to extract the data from map function. Like I've explored using set function to extract data.

Comment: You can convert it to a list with the `list()` constructor: `l = list(map(lambda x: x[0] == 'S', input_list))`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
count = list(map(lambda x:x[0]=='S',input_list)).count(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach

```
list( map( lambda x : x[0].lower() , input_list ) ).count('s')
```

Generate a list of 1st characters per item in the list, and count the number of 's' characters in that list.